# How to install python modules on a per project basis, rather than system wide?

Tags: python, distutils

I am trying to define a process for migrating django projects from my development server to my production server using git, and it's driving me crazy that distutils installs python modules system-wide.  I've read the documentation but unless I'm missing something it seems to be mostly about how to change the installation directory.  I need to be able to use different versions of the same module in different projects running on the same server, and deploy projects from git without having to download and install dependencies.

tl;dr:  I need to know how to install python modules, using distutils, into my project's source tree for version control without compromising other projects using different versions of the same module.

I'm new to python, so I apologize in advance if this is common knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). It will allow you to install packages into a separate virtual Python "root".

Answer (score 4):

Besides the already mentioned `virtualenv` which is a good option but has the potential drawback of requiring a third-party module, `Distutils` itself has options to install modules into arbitrary locations.  In particular, there is the `home scheme` which allows you to "build and maintain a personal stash of Python modules".  It's described in the Python documentation set [here](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#alternate-installation-the-home-scheme).

Comment: But you're only allowed a single home (unless you jump through hoops), and they still affect all Python scripts run by that user.

Comment: No, you can have an arbitrary number of homes: just specify `--home=/path/to/home` on the install.   The only hoop jumping necessary is to set `PYTHONPATH` to point to the home in use.  I agree `virtualenv` is an easier choice but, again, it requires the installation of additional modules which may not be desired or possible in some environments.

Comment: Agreed with Ned.  Distutils gives you --home, --prefix, --install-*, so I don’t understand why you can’t use these options to point to your custom directory.

Answer (score 1):

for completeness sake, [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) makes every day work with virtualenv a lot quicker and simpler once you are working on multiple projects and/or on multiple development platforms at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking something akin to `npm` or `yarn` of the JavaScript world or `composer` of the PHP world, then you may want to look at [pipenv](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/) (not to be confused with `pip`).  [Here's a guide to get you started.](https://realpython.com/pipenv-guide/)

Alternatively there is also [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/), which some people say is even better, but I haven't used it yet.